# ListVew SetOnItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I have listview on popupView with row which have one TextView and ImageView, and on click it starts another popupView with another listview. On my SGS4 and higher APIs all work like a charm... Started AVD on 4.1.1 API 16 to test mine app and only problem on app is that OnItemClick method,it doesn't work.

Checked StackOverflow and tried all XML properties: clickable, focusable, descendantFocusability... On root views, textViews, listView, all options with no success.

Any tips to try it out?

XML of ListeView layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select your items in Group"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lwMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:id="@+id/BtnMain"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML of row layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/Gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha" />


</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

Just to say that I have another listview on other Activity that works fine. Same code like here. Same itemclicklistener..

Comment: show your code please

Comment: We could only help if you show the code/

Comment: Just a sec, I will add XML of listview and Row layout.

Comment: You'll have to use `setOnItemClickListener` for ListView, `setOnClickListener` is for `Buttons` or other views.

Comment: Please read my question. I have working code on higher APIs... I just tried on API 16 to see my app, and saw this bug.

Comment: @Sasaman, whats your code and what error are you generating? However, from my experience, did you add an ID in your listView items? If you are using listView dynamically, you would be able to add them too from your java code. Your id would have to be unique as a default!

Comment: No errror. Just when I click on item nothing happens. On higher APIs that work like a charm... 

I have listview which I populate from my list via adapter and later set onItemClick on that listview. 

I said in my question that I have same code that works on other activity. :/

Comment: @Sasaman, get a Toast when you click anything of the list. If you are getting a toast, that means for lower APIs, you will possible need to add an ID to fetch the data. I am not so sure. Its a try

Comment: @IbtehazShawon, Thank you, I will try it... But I run debug and onClick method is never caled when I click on item. This is really wierd. Other list work well... Maybe is focus problem, but, don't know how to detect it where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this...

I had `setFocusable(false)` and `setTouchable(true)`, I removed them and it started working. Because first listview just had items without checkoboxes. And second had same parameters but with checkbox and second was worked. 
Maybe someone will have same problem. My solution was this.